# Finding Bridges in undirected Graph?

Tags: graph, bridge

A bridge in a graph means if we remove it the graph will be disconnected !
so i want to know if there is way to find all bridges in a graph :
here is an example :

```
input
    12 15
    1 2
    1 3
    2 4
    2 5
    3 5
    4 6
    6 7
    6 10
    6 11
    7 8
    8 9
    8 10
    9 10
    10 11
    11 12

Output :

    2 4
    4 6
    11 12
```

PLEASE DO NOT GIVE ME THE SOLUTION JUST A HINT ! 
Thanks

Comment: I would think you would start by finding a minimum spanning tree, to simply the number of edges you have to test.

Comment: Don't read the whole thing, read step by step to get as much hint as you want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)#Bridge-finding_algorithm  :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have the visiting number vn[v] and low number low[v] for each vertex v in graph G, then you can find if an edge is bridge of not (while unwinding the dfs recursive calls) using the following condition

```
if (low[w] > vn[v]) then (v,w) is a bridge
```

Comment: Thanks- this 1 line explanation was the aha moment where this made sense to me- the key point is "while *unwinding* the dfs recursive calls".